# I would like convert pcd to image

Tags: ros, pcl, pcd, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

My question is: As  can I visualize pcd files or the result of a function cloud_plane = cloud.extract(indices, negative=False) without rgb fiel (Can I see in rviz?)

The process is as follow:

I have a topic: /camera/depth/points [sensor_msgs/PointCloud2]
And I get points this way (in phyton):

```
    points = pc2.read_points(data,"x, y, z")
    cloud= getCloud(points)
def getCloud(points):
    points_cloud=[]
    for point in points:
    points_cloud.append([punto[0],punto[1],punto[2]])
    cloud = pcl.PointCloud(np.array(pointscloud, dtype=np.float32))
    return cloud
```

Without RGB field. Then exec RANSAC

```
    seg = cloud.make_segmenter()
    seg.set_model_type(pcl.SACMODEL_PLANE)
    seg.set_method_type(pcl.SAC_RANSAC)
    seg.set_distance_threshold(0.001)
    seg.set_distance_threshold(0.03)
    indices, model = seg.segment()
    cloud_plane = cloud.extract(indices, negative=False)
    cloud_plane.to_file("plane.pcd")
```

Plane.pcd is:

```
VERSION 0.7
FIELDS x y z
SIZE 4 4 4
TYPE F F F
COUNT 1 1 1
WIDTH 91259
HEIGHT 1
VIEWPOINT 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
POINTS 91259
DATA ascii
-4.4817686 0.35769984 7.7747769
-4.4677291 0.35769889 7.7747564
-4.4536958 0.35769838 7.7747455
-4.4396615 0.35769784 7.7747335
-4.4256258 0.35769719 7.7747192
-4.4115911 0.35769659 7.7747064
-4.3975549 0.35769585 7.7746902
```

ETC.

Some answer?

Thanks !!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206654/i-would-like-convert-pcd-to-image/) by [Lucer](https://answers.ros.org/users/21492/lucer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-04-05

Post score: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you would like to see what points are part of the plane detected by RANSAC, publish your `cloud` variable to a `PointCloud2` topic after it's been detected. Publish to a new topic name and display this PointCloud2 topic in RViz, and set the color to be different from the color of your other point clouds in the scene. Then it should be easy to see your detected plane.

---

Originally posted by [Adam Allevato](https://answers.ros.org/users/21561/adam-allevato/) with karma: 194 on 2015-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1